# MS Excel count number of unique cases with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to come up with a formula to count the number of unique cases matching multiple criteria. Here is the data:

`Anna   2015    Q3
 Anna   2015    Q4
 Anna   2016    Q1
 Anna   2016    Q2
 Anna   2016    Q2
 John   2015    Q1
 John   2015    Q1
 John   2015    Q3
 John   2016    Q2
 John   2016    Q4
 Tom    2015    Q2
 Tom    2016    Q1
 Tom    2016    Q4
 Tom    2016    Q4
 Tom    2016    Q4
 Ella   2015    Q2
 Ella   2015    Q3
 Ella   2015    Q4
 Ella   2016    Q1
 Ella   2016    Q1`

This is what I have so far

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A1:A20,A1:A20,0),MATCH(A1:A20,A1:A20,0))>0,1))`
This count the number of unique cases in A.

I want to count the number of unique cases AND filter by year and quarter at the same time. How could I go about doing that?

ie. How many people in 2016 Q1? Anna, Tom, Ella, Ella = 3 people.

edit: My cases are not true duplicates, as this is only a sample of my data. I also need a formula rather than using a Pivot table.

Comment: I'm using MS Excel 2016 64bit

Comment: Thanks pnuts for the suggestion. However I need a formula rather than use pivot table. Unfortunately I can't share my full dataset.

Comment: What do you mean by _not true duplicates_ ?

Comment: I mean that there is additional data that's not included here, ie the last two lines might look like duplicates, but they are in fact not, so I can't delete either of the rows

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to accomplish this is to Remove Duplicates after selecting you entire table, and then run `=COUNTIFS(B1:B20,B1,C1:C20,C1)` to give you the number of people in Q3 2015

Otherwise use a Pivot table to conveniently group up common occurrences by unique values

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However this is only a sample of my full data set and so they are not real duplicates.

Comment: I will update my answer in that case, thanks for specifying

Comment: use a pivot table and set the equivalent of Names as row labels, years as column labels, and count of Quarter as Values

Comment: Thanks David, but with my full dataset, I really need to be able to use a formula rather than a pivot table.